# how to find the nature of a critical point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I have this function
$$ f(x,y)=-2(x-y)^2 +x^4+y^4 $$
I need to find the nature of the critical point $(0,0)$
(we can't conclude using the Hessian Matrix)
so I notice that all critical points verify  the equation
$y=-x$ and then calculate $f(x,-x)$
$$ f(x,-x) = 2x^4-8x^2$$
and then use  Taylor's theorem to get
$$ f(x,-x) \approx -8x^2 $$
so  the point $(0,0)$ is a local maximum
but as I check the solution it states that it's a saddle point. Can anyone check where I messed up?
sorry if there's  a  bad vocabulary usage as I'm studying math in French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see only those paths where other critical points lie. It is a saddle point, since if you go along $y=-x$ (as you stated), it is a local maximum. But if you go along $y=x$, then
$$f(x,x)=2x^4$$
Therefore, origin is the point of local minimum here.

Comment: Thanks, I really was looking for this